# Launching linux process from asp.net core application fail (file not found)

Tags: c#, linux, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am creating an app in asp.net core that is run in a linux docker container using visual studio on windows. This app launches a different process depending on what platform it is on with Process.Start(). Currently, the process is launched correctly when run on my local windows machine, but when I switch to linux container I get this error (even tho both files I am attempting to launch are stored in the same directory). I did a check with File.Exists(processPath) and it shows that the file does in fact exist, but when the process is launched the Interop.Sys.ForkAndExecProcess() method seems to throw "No such file or directory" when it actually tries to launch the binary.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No such file or directory
   at Interop.Sys.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setUser, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, Int32& lpChildPid, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean shouldThrow)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

Here is the code

```
var assemblyFileInfo = new FileInfo(typeof(TemplateClass).Assembly.Location);
var rootDirectory = Path.Combine(assemblyFileInfo.DirectoryName, "HelmExecutables/Data/");
var processPath = "";

if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    processPath = Path.Combine(rootDirectory + "helm_windows.exe");
}
else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
{
    processPath = Path.Combine(rootDirectory + "helm_linux.out");
}

var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = processPath;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the `helm_linux.out` file?

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 3):

One thing that came into my mind looking your code is `processPath` can be just an empty string if both `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)` and `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)` are `false`.

What I would do is check if `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)` is `true` when the code runs in the docker image.

After that, I would `Console.WriteLine(processPath)` (or get the value of `processPath` in any other way) and try to start that executable from the command-line manually and see what happens.

Comment: I checked the process path is pointing to the correct file location.